# ¿Cómo filtrar los archivos mostrados en VS Code?

Tags: vscode

Estoy trabajando en proyectos Angular 2 con TypeScript. El IDE me muestra varios archivos que no utilizo en absoluto, usualmente los archivos JS generados al compilar mi código TypeScript. Entonces, en una carpeta pequeña me muestra varios archivos innecesarios. Aquí una muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de decirle al IDE que no quiero ver esos archivos y otros que realmente no utilizo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En base a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639564/1065197), la solución es acceder a la opción Configuración de Usuario (User Settings) y en el archivo settings.json agregar la configuración `files.exclude`. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js"
    }
}
```

Donde `"**/*.js"` filtra todos los archivos con extensión js del IDE.

Asimismo, el IDE también permite aplicar condiciones a los archivos excluidos. Por ejemplo, si se requiere evitar solo los archivos que han sido generados por la compilación de TypeScript entonces el filtro cambia a

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
    }
}
```

Para mayor información, revisar [la documentación oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace#_settings-file-sections).